# How to resolve patchy audio playback in OpenELEC?

Tags: audio, openelec

I've installed OpenELEC without modifying any configuration settings, so it's the default installation of 'Frodo'.

I've added a video source on my NAS, both with NFS & SMB

when I attempt to play movies, the video plays fine but the audio starts and stop.

Previously I had Raspbian installed and I played movies (from the same network location) using omxplayer and everything (video and audio) worked fine.

What do I need to do to approach resolution of this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was to dump OpenELEC and go with Raspbian.